# Updating nuget package with and without prerelease flag in a C# project

Tags: c#, powershell, msbuild, teamcity, nuget-package

We are using git as source control and we follow the git flow workflow.

We are using Visual Studio 2013

We are using Teamcity v8.1

We have 2 C# solutions. Solution A and solution B. Solution B uses a nuget package that solution A creates.

We are using teamcity as a build server. We have 2 build configurations that creates the Project A nuget package. One build configuration creates a prerelease version of the nuget package, the other one creates the stable version of the nuget package.

The build configuration for creating the prerelease nuget listens on the develop branch. The build configuration for the stable version listens on the master/release/hotfix branches

When we work in the develop branch we use the prerelease version of the nuget package.
But when we create a release branch we want to use the stable version of the nuget package.

What we have tried so far is:
In project B csproj file, we have added an  element in the BeforeBuild target that executes nuget.exe to update the prerelease version of the nuget package. That works well, since every time we build project B we will get the latest prerelease version of the nuget package.

But when we are in the release/master/hotfix branch we don't want the prerelease version, we want the stable one.

I've created a powershell script that is executed from project B csproj file in the BeforeBuild target

In the powershell script I can find which git branch we are in, but I haven't found a way to update the nuget package to the latest stable version using nuget.exe. If I could use the nuget cmdlets in the powershell script I could run the update-package with the version flag, but that is not supportered when using nuget.exe

Do you do something similar and how have you solved this?

Comment: sounds complicated. Why don't you use nuget server instead? Building nuget packages as a part of CI is not the way I would go with.

Comment: We use the teamcity internal nuget server to distribute the package. So solution B gets the nuget package from that feed. The complicated part is to make the switch between stable and prerelease version of the package depending on the git branch you are working in at the moment

Comment: You could have two nuget feeds, one for stable branch, and other for develop branch, and switch between these nuget feeds  based on the branch name.

Comment: What I'm opting for now is to write a powershell script that replaces the package version value in the .csproj and package.config files with the latest stable version value so Visual Studio vil restore the correct packages when rebuilding the solution

Comment: @OKB we don't have the exact same scenario but any automated update of nuget packages is messy. Our build has a complicated powershell script to figure out which version you are updating to (query the source and see what the latest version is matching some pattern, since we may want the newest 2.7.* but 3.0 is available) and then it does something similar to find and replace in the proj files so it can do a nuget restore.

Answer (score 0):

I while back I also tried to automate updating and installing packages with Powershell. As far as I know there is no way to use the Visual Studio cmdlets outside Visual Studio.

You could do everything yourself. Update packages.config, run [nuget update](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/command-line-reference#update-command), update csproj file.

It is possible your package has an `install.ps1` file. This also uses the Visual Studio cmdlets. For example, the install.ps1 can add a config file  to the Visual Studio project and set `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy if newer`.
This means you would have to add these changes to the csproj as well.